# Digital circuit for adding multiple frequencies

Tags: fpga, dac

The goal is to implement a kind of a digital piano on an FPGA.

Until now, I managed to produce individual notes using counters. Basically, I generate a square wave of a certain frequency, that corresponds to a musical note (of course, in order to do that, I rely on the frequency of the clock, but that's not an issue).

How can I design a circuit that can produce the overlapping of multiple notes? Basically, I want to be able to produce 2 sounds of different frequencies at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

When I was a teenager in the 1980's, I had an Apple II+ computer, which had a speaker output similar to the IBM PC speaker. Accessing a memory-mapped I/O port location had the effect of toggling an output connected to the speaker.

I wrote a machine-language program which played triads: three simultaneous notes. A look-up table converted note values (indexed by semitone) into counter values.  The approach was simple: initialize three counters and cycle them independently in a big loop. On any iteration when at least one of the counters has rolled around, toggle the speaker.

This routine, coupled with a BASIC program to drive it with data, played a very good sounding rendition of the synthesizer chord progression from Van Halen's *Jump*.

It's a unique sound. There is distortion, but the note separation is quite clear.

Variations in timbre can be produced, by the way, with duty cycle variation. I seem to recall that this translates to perceived volume.

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on the type of hardware you have.

If you only have a 1 bit output on the FPGA, you can oversample the audio signal (1MHz or more) and use a PWM or delta-sigma modulator, effectively generating a variable amplitude signal (you may add a low pass filter, a simple RC circuit is sufficient).

You can then add your synthesized signals (sine, square, triangle...) and generate polyphonic sounds.
For example, with a 8bits (signed) adder, set the amplitude of the two square wave generators to +50/-50.

Comment: The fpga part is sort of irrelrvant. I don't use the actual audio output. Instead, I have a regular digital output, to which I connect a speaker. So the only thing I have is a square wave, and i must generate this square wave in a way that sounds like 2 overlapping musical notes. I am also more interested in the actual circuit than the actual implementation.

Comment: "regular digital output". What is that? 8 bits? 16 bits? Signed? Unsigned?

Comment: @Kaz, it sounds to me like he has a single digital output signal (1 bit), and he is using it to drive a speaker.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is to take each output of the counters, pass it through a resistor, then connect the other end of the resistors together. Now the individual counter outputs would be attenuated while the final output would be the sum of the counter outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways (that I can think of):

1. With a DAC

   - Multiply signals individually to get different individual amplitudes.
   - Sum the signals you want to combine
   - Output n bits to the n-bit DAC
   - You can make a simple R2R DAC yourself using only resistors.
2. Without a DAC, using a single pin and a low-pass filter

   - Add the two signals
   - Modulate the output using delta-sigma modulation
   - Output through a lowpass filter (RC is simplest).

Answer (score 0):

If you're only dealing with a single, digital output, and generating square waves, the simplest way to do this is to have two (or n) counters at each desired frequency, and XOR their outputs together before outputting them to the pin. This produces an equivalent result to Kaz's toggling approach.